# Bind DNS Active Directory + Subnet

Tags: active-directory, bind, internal-dns

recently I moved from Windows DNS server to Bind which worked well so far.
The only thing which I am "missing" is "subnet answering" from Windows DNS.
E.g. I have one server with three NICs - each in a separate subnet:

- 192.168.10.1
- 192.168.20.1
- 192.168.30.1

and depending on the subnet Microsoft DNS gave the subnet IP address.

I know from searching the web that Bind has a similar feature called "Views" which could do the job.

The only thing that keeps me confused is I have one single Active Directory domain including all the subnets.

Any ideas how to solve such an issue?